# Using `:=` in data.table to sum the values of two columns in R, ignoring NAs

Tags: r, sum, data.table

I have what I think is a very simple question related to the use of data.table and the `:=` function. I don't think I quite understand the behaviour of `:=` and often I run into similar problems.

Here is some example data

```
 mat <- structure(list(
              col1 = c(NA, 0, -0.015038, 0.003817, -0.011407), 
              col2 = c(0.003745, 0.007463, -0.007407, -0.003731, -0.007491)), 
              .Names = c("col1", "col2"), 
              row.names = c(NA, 10L), 
              class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

which gives

```
> mat
         col1      col2
 1:        NA  0.003745
 2:  0.000000  0.007463
 3: -0.015038 -0.007407
 4:  0.003817 -0.003731
 5: -0.011407 -0.007491
```

I want to create a column called col3 which gives the sum of col1 and col2. If I use

```
mat[,col3 := col1 + col2]

#        col1      col2      col3
#1:        NA  0.003745        NA
#2:  0.000000  0.007463  0.007463
#3: -0.015038 -0.007407 -0.022445
#4:  0.003817 -0.003731  0.000086
#5: -0.011407 -0.007491 -0.018898
```

then I get an NA for the first row, but I want NAs to be ignored. So I tried instead

```
mat[,col3 := sum(col1,col2,na.rm=TRUE)]

#        col1      col2      col3
#1:        NA  0.003745 -0.030049
#2:  0.000000  0.007463 -0.030049
#3: -0.015038 -0.007407 -0.030049
#4:  0.003817 -0.003731 -0.030049
#5: -0.011407 -0.007491 -0.030049
```

which is not what I am after, since it is giving me the sum of all elements of col1 and col2. I think I don't quite get `:=`... How can I get the sum of the element of col1 and col2 ignoring NA values?

Not sure this is relevant, but here is my sessionInfo

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/C/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.8.3
```

Comment: Perhaps it is because there is no key to sum by.

Comment: But I don't want to sum by key, I want to sum by row!?

Comment: `rowSums` with `na.rm=TRUE`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's not a lack of understanding of data.table but rather one regarding vectorized functions in R. You can define a dyadic operator that will behave differently than the "+" operator with regard to missing values:

```
 `%+na%` <- function(x,y) {ifelse( is.na(x), y, ifelse( is.na(y), x, x+y) )}

 mat[ , col3:= col1 %+na% col2]
#-------------------------------
        col1      col2      col3
1:        NA  0.003745  0.003745
2:  0.000000  0.007463  0.007463
3: -0.015038 -0.007407 -0.022445
4:  0.003817 -0.003731  0.000086
5: -0.011407 -0.007491 -0.018898
```

You can use mrdwad's comment to do it with `sum(... , na.rm=TRUE`):

```
mat[ , col4 := sum(col1, col2, na.rm=TRUE), by=1:NROW(mat)]
```

Comment: I thought I could do something like this, but I really believed there would be a pre-programmed function or way to do this that didn't involve writing my own function... I also thought := should behave by row and perhaps there would be a way to make sum() work (perhaps by using something like with=FALSE).

Comment: It is sensible default behavior. NA rarely implies 0 as you would have it. More sensible to inherit the NA information than assume a value for it.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with data.table or :=.

Comment: @mnel but why does := sum(col1,col2) sums the entire column and not just the values of col1 and col2 in that particular column? This is why I included the reference to := and data.table

Comment: That is your misunderstanding of what := does. It assigns by reference within mat, so without a lot of internal copying. Nothing to do with references to rows in the data table.

Comment: @Vivi It's a not a bad point. For `min` and `max` there is `pmin` and `pmax`, so for `sum` why is there no `psum`? Basically you're looking for `psum`. I might ask that myself! ...

Comment: @Vivi Now asked here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123638/there-is-pmin-and-pmax-each-taking-na-rm-why-no-psum

Comment: Yes. BenBolker has remembered rowSums.

Comment: well, I didn't remember it -- I looked it up here.  I don't know if I should get any points for it, but I *did* answer the question (the "why doesn't this exist already?" part is basically unanswerable, I think ...)

Comment: @DWin this by=1:NROW(Mat) is very useful! I was looking for something like this for a while, no idea it existed!

Comment: I like the by=1:NROW solution, but it seems a lot slower than the %+na% alternative...

Answer (score 29):

This is standard `R` behaviour, nothing really to do with  `data.table`

Adding anything to `NA` will return `NA`

```
NA + 1
## NA
```

`sum` will return a single number

If you want `1 + NA` to return `1`

then you will have to run something like

```
mat[,col3 := col1 + col2]
mat[is.na(col1), col3 := col2]
mat[is.na(col2), col3 := col1]
```

To deal with when `col1` or `col2` are `NA`

---

### EDIT - an easier solution

You could also use rowSums, which has a `na.rm` argument

```
mat[ , col3 :=rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = c("col1", "col2")]
```

`rowSums` is what you want (by definition, the `rowSums` of a matrix containing `col1` and `col2`, removing `NA` values

(@JoshuaUlrich suggested this as a comment )

Comment: Ulrich's comment (your edit) seems like what I am after. I can't test now, but should be able to tomorrow.

Comment: `rowSums` is by far the fastest option since it's vectorized