# There is pmin and pmax each taking na.rm, why no psum?

Tags: r

It seems that R might be missing an obvious simple function: `psum`. Does it exist as a different name, or is it in a package somewhere?

```
x = c(1,3,NA,5)
y = c(2,NA,4,1)

min(x,y,na.rm=TRUE)    # ok
[1] 1
max(x,y,na.rm=TRUE)    # ok
[1] 5
sum(x,y,na.rm=TRUE)    # ok
[1] 16

pmin(x,y,na.rm=TRUE)   # ok
[1] 1 3 4 1
pmax(x,y,na.rm=TRUE)   # ok
[1] 2 3 4 5
psum(x,y,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 3 3 4 6                             # expected result
Error: could not find function "psum"   # actual result
```

I realise that `+` is already like `psum`, but what about `NA`?

```
x+y                      
[1]  3 NA NA  6        # can't supply `na.rm=TRUE` to `+`
```

Is there a case to add `psum`?  Or have I missed something.

This question is a follow up from this question :
[Using `:=` in data.table to sum the values of two columns in R, ignoring NAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106645/using-in-data-table-to-sum-the-values-of-two-columns-in-r-ignoring-nas)

Comment: Starting the countdown timer til we see the contributed patch on r-devel:  10, 9, 8, 7, ...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: Has that timer expired yet?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel how 'bout now?

Comment: One answer could be just `function(...) { rowSums( cbind( ...) , na.rm=TRUE) }`? Should succeed with any mixture of vector or dataframe of appropriate dimension. Does give zero for NA,NA when na.rm=TRUE, but so does `sum`. Still no data.table::psum as of version 1.9.6

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel still no?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Following @JoshUlrich's comment on the previous question,

```
psum <- function(...,na.rm=FALSE) { 
    rowSums(do.call(cbind,list(...)),na.rm=na.rm) }
```

**edit**: from Sven Hohenstein:

```
psum2 <- function(...,na.rm=FALSE) { 
    dat <- do.call(cbind,list(...))
    res <- rowSums(dat, na.rm=na.rm) 
    idx_na <- !rowSums(!is.na(dat))
    res[idx_na] <- NA
    res 
}

x = c(1,3,NA,5,NA)
y = c(2,NA,4,1,NA)
z = c(1,2,3,4,NA)

psum(x,y,na.rm=TRUE)
## [1] 3 3 4 6 0
psum2(x,y,na.rm=TRUE)
## [1] 3 3 4 6 NA

n = 1e7
x = sample(c(1:10,NA),n,replace=TRUE)
y = sample(c(1:10,NA),n,replace=TRUE)
z = sample(c(1:10,NA),n,replace=TRUE)

library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(psum(x,y,z,na.rm=TRUE),
          psum2(x,y,z,na.rm=TRUE),
          pmin(x,y,z,na.rm=TRUE), 
          pmax(x,y,z,na.rm=TRUE), replications=20)

##                          test replications elapsed relative 
## 4  pmax(x, y, z, na.rm = TRUE)           20  26.114    1.019 
## 3  pmin(x, y, z, na.rm = TRUE)           20  25.632    1.000 
## 2 psum2(x, y, z, na.rm = TRUE)           20 164.476    6.417
## 1  psum(x, y, z, na.rm = TRUE)           20  63.719    2.486
```

Sven's version (which arguably is the correct one) is quite a bit slower,
although whether it matters obviously depends on the application.
Anyone want to hack up an inline/Rcpp version?

As for why this doesn't exist: don't know, but good luck getting R-core to make additions like this ... I can't offhand think of a sufficiently widespread `*misc` package into which this could go ...

Follow up thread by Matthew on r-devel is here (which seems to confirm) :
[r-devel: There is pmin and pmax each taking na.rm, how about psum?](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/There-is-pmin-and-pmax-each-taking-na-rm-how-about-psum-tp4647841.html)

Comment: Those don't return the required result. They remove the `NA`. The desired result is a length 4 vector : `3 3 4 6`.

Comment: Not `pdiff` because `psum(x,-y,na.rm=TRUE)` would do that. Perhaps `ptimes` too, but not `pdiv` as well for the same reason. But I guess that `psum` is a more common case than `ptimes`.

Comment: Yes that's one implementation of `psum`, but it would be very inefficient. I wasn't asking how might `psum` be implemented, but, what I asked really.

Comment: @MatthewDowle I'm not sure we *can* answer what you really asked - There aren't too many R Core people on [so] - one or two yes but wouldn't you be better asking that question on R-Devel?

Comment: @GavinSimpson Ok will do. I know I'm much better off asking here first _then_ asking on r-devel if it survives you guys.

Comment: I don't think R-Core *will* answer.  And I don't really think there is an answer, other than "no-one thought of it at the time, or when they did think of it they thought it wasn't necessary" -- and now they won't want to add it to base R because adding *anything* is considered a burden. Much discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065835/proposing-feature-requests-to-the-r-core-team/

Comment: Just checked performances of `pmin`,`pmax` and `psum` from this answer. 3 vectors of length `1e5`, `1e3` replications and results were pretty similar: 6.24, 6.21, 7.55 seconds respectively. While few other versions of `psum` that I found got 30 and more.

Comment: @Julius, feel free to edit my answer if you like (or post your benchmarks as an answer)

Comment: @Julius `n=1e5`? `7.26/1000==0.007`. i.e. try `benchmark` with `replications=3` and scale up the data size, instead.

Comment: This `psum` function is a good idea. Just one addition: Both `psum` and `pmax` return `NA` if all elements (at the same position in the vectors) are `NA` (even if `na.rm = TRUE`). Check `pmin(NA, NA, na.rm = TRUE)`. I slightly modified your function to achieve the same behavior for `psum`: `psum <- function(...,na.rm=FALSE) { dat <- do.call(cbind,list(...)); "[<-"(rowSums(dat, na.rm=na.rm), rowSums(is.na(dat)) == ncol(dat), NA) }`

Comment: @SvenHohenstein: good point. My only concerns are that (1) of course this will slow things down further (if that is an issue) and (2) I would probably split your second statement into several separate lines: it's a little *too* clever/compact for me ...

Comment: (1) I agree that the drop in speed is the major drawback of this approach. (2) Here's a modified version: `psum <- function(...,na.rm=FALSE) { dat <- do.call(cbind,list(...)); res <- rowSums(dat, na.rm=na.rm); idx_na <- !rowSums(!is.na(dat)); res[idx_na] <- NA; return(res) }`

Comment: It amuses me that the discussion on r-devel followed almost the same lines as the one here. I'm mildly disappointed but not at all surprised that R-core doesn't seem to have nibbled.

Comment: @BenBolker I'm not surprised either. A flat "no" would have been worse so I'm holding out hope and following step 1 of your good advice [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8066062/403310) i.e. waiting a week. The C implementation is very easy - just a matter of tweaking the existing `pmin` and `pmax` C source.

Answer (score 9):

After a quick search on CRAN, there are at least 3 packages that have a `psum` function. `rccmisc`, `incadata` and `kit`. `kit` seems to be the fastest. Below reproducing the example of Ben Bolker.

```
benchmark(
  rccmisc::psum(x,y,z,na.rm=TRUE),
  incadata::psum(x,y,z,na.rm=TRUE),
  kit::psum(x,y,z,na.rm=TRUE), 
  psum(x,y,z,na.rm=TRUE),
  psum2(x,y,z,na.rm=TRUE),
  replications=20
)
#                                    test replications elapsed relative
# 2 incadata::psum(x, y, z, na.rm = TRUE)           20   20.05   14.220
# 3      kit::psum(x, y, z, na.rm = TRUE)           20    1.41    1.000
# 4           psum(x, y, z, na.rm = TRUE)           20    8.04    5.702
# 5          psum2(x, y, z, na.rm = TRUE)           20   20.44   14.496
# 1  rccmisc::psum(x, y, z, na.rm = TRUE)           20   23.24   16.482
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach whose advantage is to **also work with matrices**, just like `pmin` and `pmax`.

```r
psum <- function(..., na.rm = FALSE) {
  plus_na_rm <- function(x, y) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x) + ifelse(is.na(y), 0, y)
  Reduce(if(na.rm) plus_na_rm else `+`, list(...))
}

x = c(1,3,NA,5)
y = c(2,NA,4,1)

psum(x, y)
#> [1]  3 NA NA  6
psum(x, y, na.rm = TRUE)
#> [1] 3 3 4 6

# With matrices
A <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)
B <- matrix(c(NA, 2:8, NA), nrow = 3)

psum(A, B)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]   NA    8   14
#> [2,]    4   10   16
#> [3,]    6   12   NA
psum(A, B, na.rm = TRUE)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    8   14
#> [2,]    4   10   16
#> [3,]    6   12    9
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

One caveat: if an element is `NA` across all the summed objects and `na.rm = TRUE`, the result will be `0` (and not `NA`).

For example:

```r
psum(NA, NA, na.rm = TRUE)
#> [1] 0
```

Comment: base `ifelse` and `Reduce`? that is going to be terribly slow