# counting the occurrence of NA's in multiple vectors in r

Tags: r, vector, na

Hi guys this is my first post, i need help summing the number of NA's in a few vectors

for example..

```
c1<-c(1,2,NA,3,4)
c2<-c(NA,1,2,3,4) 
c3<-c(NA,1,2,3,4)
```

how would i get a result that only sums the number of NA's in the vector?

```
the.result.i.want<-c(2,0,1,0,0)
```

Comment: Maybe relevant: [There is pmin and pmax each taking na.rm, why no psum?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123638/there-is-pmin-and-pmax-each-taking-na-rm-why-no-psum)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question isn't well-phrased, but it looks like you want the result of `colSums` used with `rbind` and `is.na`:

```
> colSums(is.na(rbind(c1, c2, c3)))
[1] 2 0 1 0 0
```

Comment: hey @user2889147:   Oddly enough, this is almost exactly the answer I posted when this fellow (mattbju2013) posted this to r-help. I used apply instead of colSums but it's the same operation.