# R using max function in data table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm using R and have a problem in a `data.table`

Both of these commands return `NA` for all rows:

```
AfAm[, sizediffpos := max(0,sizediff)]
AfAm[, sizediffpos := max(0,sizediff, na.rm = TRUE)]
```

Is there any way I can rectify the error?

Comment: `?pmax` instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994543/how-can-i-take-pairwise-maximum-between-two-vectors-in-r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As rawr points out, the correct way is to use `pmax`:

```
AfAm[, sizediffpos := pmax(0,sizediff)]
```