# Find max value for multiple rle in r

Tags: r, plot, max, rle

I have a list of RLEs that looks like this:

```
RleList of length 3
$item1
  Lengths:   1   3   1   2   1   5
  Values :  NA   0   4  13  14  17

$item2
  Lengths:   4   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
  Values :   0  18 102 108 131 167 181  48  31  29

$item3
  Lengths:   1   3   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
  Values :   0   1  20  56  65  77 106  50  47  44   7
```

I used it to make a plot that has multiple lines in one plot. I want to find a line of maximum values of the 3 lines and plot that into a new plot. How can I achieve my goal? Do I need to convert the RLE to a vector and then find the max values for each position?

Comment: What values do you want to get?

Comment: `sapply(RleList, \(x) max(x$Values))`

Comment: This might be easier to answer if you `dput(RleList)` and also provide the expected output (you can write this out manually, or explain the logic a bit more with a couple of example values)

Answer (score 0):

So I found out the solution!

I first turned them into vectors. And then used `pmax` to find the pairwise max for all of them!

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994543/how-can-i-take-pairwise-parallel-maximum-between-two-vectors?rq=1) helped a lot!