# Adding two variables with missing data

Tags: r, missing-data

This is probably a really simple question for regular R users but I can't seem to find the solution.
I want to add two variables with missing data.

`x1<-c(NA,3,NA,5)
 x2<-c(NA,NA,4,3)
 x3<-x1+x2
 x3
 [1] NA NA NA 8`

But what I really want is:

```
[1] NA 3 4 8
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. How can I keep the NA's?

Comment: This is very similar to: [There is pmin and pmax each taking na.rm, why no psum?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123638/there-is-pmin-and-pmax-each-taking-na-rm-why-no-psum)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To keep the `NA` if both are `NA` (ripping off @Ben Bolker's approach of using `cbind`):

```
apply(cbind(x1, x2), 1, function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, sum(x, na.rm=T)))
# [1] NA  3  4  8
```

Or, if you prefer using the `rowSums` function (which is attractive because it's vectorized whereas the `apply` and `mapply` solutions are not):

```
rowSums(cbind(x1, x2), na.rm=T) + ifelse(is.na(x1) & is.na(x2), NA, 0)
# [1] NA  3  4  8
```

Neither of these would be quite as fast as an Rcpp function (which would only need to loop through the two inputs once):

```
library(Rcpp)
sum.na.ign <- cppFunction("
NumericVector sumNaIgn(NumericVector x, NumericVector y) {
  const int n = x.size();
  NumericVector out(n);
  for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (R_IsNA(x[i])) {
      out[i] = y[i];
    } else if (R_IsNA(y[i])) {
      out[i] = x[i];
    } else {
      out[i] = x[i] + y[i];
    }
  }
  return out;
}")
sum.na.ign(x1, x2)
# [1] NA  3  4  8
```

We can benchmark (along with the solution based on `mapply` from @J. Won.) for larger vectors:

```
# First two functions along with mapply-based solution from @J. Won.
f1 <- function(x1, x2) apply(cbind(x1, x2), 1, function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, sum(x, na.rm=T)))
f2 <- function(x1, x2) rowSums(cbind(x1, x2), na.rm=T) + ifelse(is.na(x1) & is.na(x2), NA, 0)
NAsum <- function(...) {
  if(any(!is.na(c(...)))) return(sum(..., na.rm=TRUE))
  return(NA)
}
jwon <- function(x1, x2) mapply(NAsum, x1, x2)

set.seed(144)
x1 <- sample(c(NA, 1:10), 10000, replace=T)
x2 <- sample(c(NA, 1:10), 10000, replace=T)
all.equal(jwon(x1, x2), f1(x1, x2), f2(x1, x2), sum.na.ign(x1, x2))
# [1] TRUE
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(jwon(x1, x2), f1(x1, x2), f2(x1, x2), sum.na.ign(x1, x2))
# Unit: microseconds
#                expr       min         lq       mean     median        uq       max neval
#        jwon(x1, x2) 24044.658 28387.4280 35580.3434 35134.9940 38175.661 91476.032   100
#          f1(x1, x2) 37516.769 46664.6390 52293.5265 51570.2690 56647.063 77576.091   100
#          f2(x1, x2)  2588.820  2738.0740  2930.4106  2833.4880  2974.745  5187.684   100
#  sum.na.ign(x1, x2)    97.988   109.8575   132.9849   123.0795   142.725   533.275   100
```

The `rowSums` solution is vectorized and therefore faster than the `apply` and `mapply` solutions (these would feel slow with vectors of length 1 million) but the custom Rcpp solution is more than 10x faster than the `rowSums` approach. Your vectors would probably need to be pretty large for the Rcpp to be useful compared to the `rowSums`.

Answer (score 7):

```
mapply(sum, x1, x2, na.rm=TRUE)
```

EDIT: if we want a more complicated version as requested in comment, I think it requires a custom function

```
NAsum <- function(...) {
  if(any(!is.na(c(...)))) return(sum(..., na.rm=TRUE))
  return(NA)
}

mapply(NAsum, x1, x2)
```

Comment: updated. and this is why I play this game: to teach myself new things (how to pass "...")

Answer (score 5):

There isn't an option to `+` to suppress `NA` values, but you can:

```
rowSums(cbind(x1,x2),na.rm=TRUE)
## [1] 2 3 4 8
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use following code given as answer above to solve a problem I had of summing up more than two variables in a data frame. I'm not sure if this is allowed on the platform, but still wanted to share.

> apply(cbind(x1, x2), 1, function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, sum(x,
>   na.rm=T)))

Following is my data

```
    x1  x2  x3  VAt
1   NA  NA  a   NA
2   3   NA  b   1
3   NA  4   c   2
4   5   3   d   NA
```

> One <- read_csv("~/One.csv")
>
> One$use <- apply(cbind(One$x1, One$x2, One$VAt), 
>                     1,  function(x) 
>           ifelse(all(is.na(x)), 
>                  NA, sum(x, na.rm=T)))
>
> One$use1 <- with(One, apply(cbind(x1, x2, VAt), 
>                    1, 
>                    function(x) 
>                      ifelse(all(is.na(x)), 
>                             NA, sum(x, na.rm=T))))

And following is the output.

```
    X1  x1  x2  x3  VAt use use1
1   1   NA  NA  a   NA  NA  NA
2   2   3   NA  b   1   4   4
3   3   NA  4   c   2   6   6
4   4   5   3   d   NA  8   8
```

Thank you @swhusky for the question and @josliber for the answer.