# A + B with NA in r

Tags: r, na

I want to calculate A+B in r

```
A <- c(NA,2,3,4,5)
B <- c(1,2,3,4,NA)
```

The ideal output is:

```
(1,4,6,8,5)
```

Is there a way to achieve this without replacing NA with 0? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123638/there-is-pmin-and-pmax-each-taking-na-rm-why-no-psum

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would be your expected output for A*B and A/B?

Comment: Sorry, I made a bad example here. I just wanted to say that I need to get the mean or sum or some other analysis out of many datasets, so replacing the NA with 0 may introduce bias at some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always implement your own sum:

```r
mysum <- function(...) {
  plus <- function(x, y) {
    ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x) + ifelse(is.na(y), 0, y)
  }
  Reduce(plus, list(...))
}

A <- c(NA,2,3,4,5)
B <- c(1,2,3,4,NA)

mysum(A, B)
#> [1] 1 4 6 8 5
mysum(A, A)
#> [1]  0  4  6  8 10
mysum(A, B, A, B)
#> [1]  2  8 12 16 10
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: @Jeremy what do you mean by a matrix? This would definitely not work for a matrix

Comment: @rawr Sure it does: `A <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3) ; B <- matrix(c(NA, 2:8, NA), nrow = 3) ; mysum(A, B)`

Comment: @asac op wants a vector, yes?

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with `rowSums`:

```
rowSums(data.frame(A,B), na.rm=TRUE)
```